# Residue at infinity of a function which approaches a finite limit at infinity (follow-up question)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, residue-calculus

This is a follow-up to a question about [computing the residue at infinity of a function which approaches a finite limit at infinity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010960/residue-at-infinity-of-a-function-which-approaches-a-finite-limit-at-infinity). Is it possible to prove that the residue at infinity is $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} z^2 f'(z)$ without explicitly using a Laurent series expansion of $f(z)$. I tried proving it as follows.

**Proof:**

We will first suppose that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z) = 0$ and then argue that the result still holds when the limit is not zero. Let

$$
g(z) = \left \{
\begin{array}{cl}
f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) & \mathrm{for\ }z \neq 0, \\
0 & \mathrm{for\ } z = 0.
\end{array} \right .
$$

Then,

\begin{align}
\underset{z = \infty}{\mathrm{Res}}\left(f(z)\right) &= \underset{z = 0}{\mathrm{Res}}\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\right) \\
&= \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} -\frac{1}{z} f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) \\
&= \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} -\frac{g(z)}{z} \\
&= -\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{g(z) - g(0)}{z - 0} \\
&= -g'(0).
\end{align}

Now $g'(z) = -\frac{1}{z^2}f'\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$, and so therefore

\begin{align}
\underset{z = \infty}{\mathrm{Res}} = -g'(0) &= \lim_{z \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{z^2} f'\left(\frac{1}{z}\right) \\
&= \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} z^2 f'(z),
\end{align}

whenever $f(z) \rightarrow 0$ as $z \rightarrow 0$.

Now the residue at infinity is not changed when a constant $c$ is added to $f(z)$. In this case $\lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} f(z) = c$. Therefore it follows that

$$
\underset{z = \infty}{\mathrm{Res}}\left(f(z)\right) = -g'(0) = \lim_{z \rightarrow \infty} z^2 f'(z)
$$

as required. $\square$

Is the proof correct? The part I'm not sure about is the last paragraph.

Comment: If you can say why the residue doesn't change when we add a constant, it's correct. If you cannot, that's a hole we must plug.

Comment: Is it sufficient to add an extra sentence saying that $$\mathrm{Res}_{z = \infty}(f(z) + c) = \mathrm{Res}_{z = \infty}(f(z)) + \mathrm{Res}_{z = \infty}(c) = \mathrm{Res}_{z = \infty}(f(z)) + 0 = \mathrm{Res}_{z = \infty}(f(z))?$$

Comment: Probably. If you know why a constant function has residue $0$, that's all. If not, make the argument for that.

Comment: Ah, ok. It sounds correct, but I don't think I've actually every proved that a constant function has residue 0. Will try proving that as further practice. Thanks!

Comment: It's straightforward from the definition. A higher-level argument uses the fact that the sum of all residues of a function that is holomorphic on $\widehat{\mathbb{C}}\setminus F$, where $F$ is a finite set, is $0$. Since a constant doesn't have any singularities in $\mathbb{C}$, the sum of residues is just the residue at $\infty$.